# how to access sqlite databse from two activites for reading and writing

Tags: android, database, sqlite

now i want two of my activities gain access to the same databases. i have one main activity and second activity.. main activity inserts some value into the database and after started the second activity by main activity , the second one should call the same database and read the tables and should return the list..in my case its not working main activity successfully inserted the values into the database but second activity failed to return the values. it always returns empty list...please help me...here is the coding for second activity accessing the database...

```
public class SecondActivty extends Activity
{
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen);

    List<String> objlist=new ArrayList<String>();
    objlist=objdatabase.getdetail(accessCode);
    if(objlist.size()!=0)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"got values", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
   {
       Toast.makeText(this,"no value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
}
```

}

```
public List<String> getdetail(String code)
{
List<String> objDetail=new ArrayList<String>();
Cursor cGetDetail=objDB.rawQuery("SELECT TITLE,LOCATION,DATE FROM HISTORY WHERE CODE='"+Code+"'",     null);             
        if(cGetDetail.getCount()>0)
        {
            if(cGetDetail.moveToFirst())
            {

                String sTitle = cGetDetail.getString(cGetDetail.getColumnIndex("TITLE"));
                String sLocation = cGetDetail.getString(cGetDetail.getColumnIndex("LOCATION"));
                String sDate=cGetDetail.getString(cGetDetail.getColumnIndex("DATE"));
                objDetail.add(new String(String.valueOf(sTitle)));
                objDetail.add(new String(String.valueOf(sLocation)));
                objDetail.add(new String(String.valueOf(sDate)));
            }
        }

        return objDetail;

public DB extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
public DB(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    objContext = context;

    try {
        createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    openDataBase();

}

private boolean checkDataBase(){

    //SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    boolean checkDB = false;
    try
            {
        String sMyPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        //checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(sMyPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
         File dbfile = new File(sMyPath);
        checkDB = dbfile.exists();
    }
    catch(SQLiteException e)
    {

    }
    return checkDB;

}


public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    boolean bDatabaseExist = checkDataBase();

    if(bDatabaseExist)
    {
        //do nothing - database already exist
    }
    else
    {

        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try 
        {
            copyDataBase();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    try
    {
        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream objMyInput = objContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String sOutFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream objMyOutput = new FileOutputStream(sOutFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int nLength;
        while ((nLength = objMyInput.read(buffer))>0)
        {
            objMyOutput.write(buffer, 0, nLength);
        }

        //Close the streams
        objMyOutput.flush();
        objMyOutput.close();
        objMyInput.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(objContext, "Copy Error-"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

    //Open the database
    String sMyPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    objDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(sMyPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

}
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for `getdetail` method please? This does not the important part

Comment: Can you also add the code where you create your table and insert the rows?

Comment: i have added the value in main activity and its showing the values while calling from mainactivity but in second activity while calling the getdetail method its not showing....???? :-(

Comment: Have you checked for spelling mistakes in the query?

Comment: if there is spelling mistakes in query then it will show error know while debugging it doesnot get into the if loop of getdetail() its returning null value..:-(

Comment: Have you tried using `Cursor cGetDetail = objDB.query("HISTORY",new String{"TITLE","LOCATION","DATE"},"Code=?",new String[]{Code},null,null);`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to close your database when your done with it from the First Activity

```
objdatabase.close();
```

> Then in your Second Activity you need to instanciate you DBHelper and
>   open your database then call objdatabase.getdetail(accessCode); don't forget to close it again

Comment: yes i have closed the database in onpause() in activity and in second activity i have opened the database...but returning empty list...:-( please help me

Comment: can you give us your first activity code ? so we can help

Comment: In first activity i have just opened the database and inserted the values and started the second activity meanwhile in onpause() i have closed the database an in second one i have again opened the databse....but not showing...:-(

Comment: add this line cGetDetail.close(); before the return objDetail;

Comment: added but no changes ehh..:-( while debugging  it doesnot get into the if loop of getdetail() its returning null value..:-(

Comment: well you need to give me your code of db instantiation

Answer (score 0):

Your data access code should be in separate 'data accessor' classes, not in the activities. The data access code should be responsible for opening and closing the database connection. That means you keep your data access code separate and clean and you can call it from any activity. Here's a good link to a tutorial that explains how to structure your data access classes [Vogella data access](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Comment: yes i am having database access method in the DB class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper...

Comment: Your DB class is responsible for opening and closing connections to the database, creating the tables etc but you should have another layer above that which deals with passing the query to your DB class, mapping the cursor results returned into objects, etc. So if you have a table that deals with, say, widgets, then you have a data access class that calls your DB class for widgets. And if you have another entity with records in another table, then you have a separate data accessor that calls your Db class to get those entities.